# ATL DCOM Object creation fails in VS 2010 Build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, atl, dcom

We have a DCOM server which works fine in Win 7 64 Bit for the VS 2008 build. In the case of VS 2010 build, the client side object creation fails with "Server Creation Failed" error message. The class  definition is given below.

When debugged, we have seen that a message with message id 1024, has received in the message loop, but `DispatchMessage` does not route the message, to create  `CICEConnect` object.  In the VS 2008 build, `DispatchMessage` routes the call to create `CICEConnect` object.  I believe this creates the issue

The server application was stated when the client tries to create the object.  The DCOM server is running in the local machine

How can I debug the issue further?

```
void RunMessageLoop() throw()
      {
            MSG msg;
            while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
            {
                  TranslateMessage(&msg);
                  DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
      }
```

---

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CICEConnect :
      public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
      public CComCoClass<CICEConnect, &CLSID_ICEConnect>,
      public IDispatchImpl<IICEConnect, &IID_IICEConnect, &LIBID_ICEConnectServerLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{
public:
      CICEConnect()
      {
      }
      DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON(CICEConnect)
DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_ICECONNECT)


BEGIN_COM_MAP(CICEConnect)
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IICEConnect)
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
END_COM_MAP()

};
```

---

If I Skip `p->Release();` in the following `RegisterClassObject`, the COM Object creation succeeds.

```
struct _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY30
{
       HRESULT WINAPI RegisterClassObject(
              _In_ DWORD dwClsContext,
              _In_ DWORD dwFlags)
       {
              IUnknown* p = NULL;
              if (pfnGetClassObject == NULL)
                     return S_OK;
              HRESULT hRes = pfnGetClassObject(pfnCreateInstance, __uuidof(IUnknown), (LPVOID*) &p);
              if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
                     hRes = CoRegisterClassObject(*pclsid, p, dwClsContext, dwFlags, &dwRegister);
              if (p != NULL)
                     p->Release();
              return hRes;
       }
// Added in ATL 3.0
       void (WINAPI *pfnObjectMain)(_In_ bool bStarting);
};
```

The Code used to create the COM object is given below

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
      CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

                      COSERVERINFO server;
                      memset(&server,0,sizeof(COSERVERINFO));
                      COAUTHINFO athn;
                      ZeroMemory(&athn, sizeof(COAUTHINFO));
                      athn.dwAuthnLevel = RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE;
                      athn.dwAuthnSvc = RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT;
                      athn.dwAuthzSvc = RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE;
                      athn.dwCapabilities = EOAC_NONE;
                      athn.dwImpersonationLevel = RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE;
                      athn.pAuthIdentityData = NULL;
                      athn.pwszServerPrincName = NULL;
                      server.pAuthInfo = &athn;
                      server.pwszName = L"\\\\localhost";
                      server.dwReserved1 = 0;
                      server.dwReserved2 = 0;
                      MULTI_QI mqi = {&IID_IICEConnect, NULL, S_OK};

                      // Access the PMC on the given machine
                        HRESULT hRes = CoCreateInstanceEx(CLSID_ICEConnect,NULL,
                                        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER,&server,1,&mqi);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: You further debugging is to see what activity you have on your server side: `1` Is `CICEConnect::CICEConnect()` ever called, `2` Is its class factory `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` ever called.

Comment: IClassFactory::CreateInstance is not called, But the class factory object is created

Comment: Which suggests that there is nothing wrong with class implementation itself. It is either security, or coclass registration that prevent from instantiation.

Comment: Updated my post with some additional information. If I comment the object release of Class Factory Object After registering it, the COM Object is created

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that `DispatchMessage` is a system call and its implementation is beyond the control of VS2008 & VS2010? maybe you do not handle correct message to create the control! for example a change in the SDK may generate your error. message with ID 1024 is `WM_USER` and system do not handle it normally. handling this message is up to the user code